# Is there a setting for maximum indent level?

Tags: indentation, folding

After setting manual fold by indent with `set foldmethod=indent`, I found that seems the max indent level is around 20, i.e. more than 20 levels will collapse together.

May I know if there is a setting in vim for maximum indent level that support fold and unfold?

Comment: I find it surprising, that you would need more than 20 levels. What is the use case please?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt a detailed c++ calltree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting, but unfortunately, 20 is the maximum supported number of nested folds. See [`:help 'foldnestmax'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27foldnestmax%27):

> Using more than 20 doesn't work, because the internal limit is 20.

<del>You could try working around this by using a custom [fold expression](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#fold-expr). Note that the `indent()` function can be used in `'foldexpr'` to get the indent of a line. There may also be plugins that provide slightly different styles of indent folding.</del> **Update**: Christian Brabandt points out in the comments that my interpretation of the :help was inaccurate. While the `'foldnestmax'` option applies to the indent and syntax methods, [the internal limit](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/45da32964d6e7e635af8fcf0b42e974b0b536ed3/src/fold.c#L43) is hard coded across *all* fold methods.

Comment: Using foldexpression won't make you bypass the max level. It seems this level is hard coded across all fold methods.

Comment: maybe the only hack is change vim's source code then compile...

Comment: I think you need to change the following line: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/45da32964d6e7e635af8fcf0b42e974b0b536ed3/src/fold.c#L43